# Adding the content of span into div and making it visible on button click

Tags: javascript

I am getting some content into  when user enters `url` on my page.
I want, when user click on the button the content should be set to `<div>` and after that div should appear.

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/qx4AB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some typos in your fiddle.  Here is a modified version:

http://jsfiddle.net/yRsqJ/1/

HTML:

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;height:40px;display:none;" id="d1">
</div> 
<span id="s1">This should be included into into div on button click</span>
<button type="submit" onclick="myfunc()">Button</button>
```

SCRIPT:

```
function myfunc()
{

document.getElementById('d1').innerText=document.getElementById('s1').innerText;
document.getElementById('d1').style.display='block';
}
```

By the way, why not just use jquery if you can.

Here is one way of doing it in jquery:

http://jsfiddle.net/qx4AB/17/

HTML:

```
<div id="d1">
</div> 
<span id="s1">This should be included into into div on button click</span>
<button id="btn" type="submit">Button</button>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$('#btn').click(function()
{
    myfunc();
});

function myfunc()
{
var div = $('#d1');

var spanText = $('#s1').text();

 div.text(spanText);

 d1.show();
}
```

Comment: I welcome jquery, but I am not sound with it. I appreciate if you add and let me know good reference for jquery which shows basic example!

Comment: @xaisoft innerText is not cross browser compatible. it wont work in mozilla

Comment: Hey it works in your fiddle. I have taken same script here but what's issue? http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/qx4AB/12/

Comment: @shadow: I experienced, Can you please give solution for this?

Comment: @Programming_crazy use document.getElementById('s1').innerText || document.getElementById('s1').textContent

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<body>
<div height="40" style="display:none" width="50" border="2" id="d1">
</div>
<span id="s1">This should be included into into div on button click</span>
<button type="submit" onclick="myfunc();"> Button</button>
</body>
<script>
    function myfunc() {
        var html = document.getElementById("s1").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("d1").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML = html;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but no change. Please see : http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/qx4AB/10/

Comment: worked fine in my pc..

could you please check your console ?